# Is it possible to tell if a file is associated with a service, or alternatively what config files are associated with a service?

Tags: linux, systemd, services

Suppose I have a file, `/etc/foo.conf` and I'd like to know what service actually uses `/etc/foo.conf`. Or, alternatively, assume I have a service named `foo.service` and I would like to know what configuration files the service uses. Is there a way to determine either from the file what service(s) use the file, or for each service what configuration files that use?

I'd assume that `fuser` or `lsof` would give me the information I desire; however, running fuser on `/etc/rsyslog.conf` returns nothing, even though rsyslog is enabled and running.

For a more concrete example, here's some output that tells me nothing at all about what configuration files the service uses:

```
[user@host ~]# systemctl cat rsyslog
# /usr/lib/systemd/system/rsyslog.service
[Unit]
Description=System Logging Service
;Requires=syslog.socket
Wants=network.target network-online.target
After=network.target network-online.target
Documentation=man:rsyslogd(8)
Documentation=https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/

[Service]
Type=notify
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/rsyslog
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n $SYSLOGD_OPTIONS
UMask=0066
StandardOutput=null
Restart=on-failure

# Increase the default a bit in order to allow many simultaneous
# files to be monitored, we might need a lot of fds.
LimitNOFILE=16384

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
;Alias=syslog.service

[user@host ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/rsyslog
# Options for rsyslogd
# Syslogd options are deprecated since rsyslog v3.
# If you want to use them, switch to compatibility mode 2 by "-c 2"
# See rsyslogd(8) for more details
SYSLOGD_OPTIONS=""
```

Comment: If a program opens, e.g., a config file, then the name of the file is contained in the program's binary. Use `strings /usr/sbin/rsyslogd` and look for filenames.

Comment: That generally doesn't work, @waltinator, because in most cases configuration file paths are computed at runtime from fragments (e.g., postfix, most simple things), or they don't exist at all and a program simple scans a directory (apache, sysctl,...) , or the configuration is actually runtime executed code and loads arbitrary libraries as further configuration (perl-written services liked to do that! But also things like chat/messaging servers written in python,...), or the configuration doesn't exist altogether but is part of compiled-in preprocessor constants (Sendmail!)...

Comment: @MarcusMüller It's always worked for me. Referenced files are 1) Passed in as command line parameters;  2) Hardcoded in the binary; or 3) Pointed to by an environment variable, traditionally in all upper case, also hardcoded in the binary. The latter two cases are subject to `strings`. Or, one could watch which files `program` opens with `strace -e open program`.

Comment: The strace approach is indeed very reliable in telling you which files get read - can be a bit overwhelming if you don't know yet what to look for, but definitely works! - but it can't tell you which files *might* get read (but maybe don't exist yet)

Comment: I've been using an `strace` approach for this and it works, was just hoping for an easier solution. The `strings` approach is rather interesting though. The other thing that could be useful for default files/paths would be to inspect the package associated with the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Such "ownership information" for files does not exist. And conversely, "services" are just executables that can open any file they have access to - so there's also no inherent telling which files a service will read to load configuration.

All you can do is read documentation.

Comment: Or, for the Real Truth, read the source.